# What is a Linux command to find files containing some strings but not another?

Tags: string, grep, xargs

I'm trying to search a lot of XML files for certain strings but not other strings, and I'm having trouble putting a command together to do it. I only want it to list the file names that match the inclusion/exclusion criteria. I've been trying:

```
find . -name *.xml -exec grep -li "string1\|string2" {} \; | xargs grep -Li "string3\|string4"
```

But I'm having trouble because the file names that are returned from [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_%28command%29) have spaces in their names and the second [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) breaks them all into little chunks and of course doesn't find such files. I've tried adding `-0` to the [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), and it removes the errors, but it says "File name too long" and only executes the first grep.

How do I tweak this command to have it work properly on files with spaces in the names?

Comment: Doesnt this belong to super user?

Comment: bash scripting is both programming related and system-maintenance related so I'd say it belongs at either site.

Comment: Not on a unix box at the moment, but I'd guess (assuming GNU grep), you could try something like `find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -liZ "string1\|string2" {} \; | xargs -0 grep -Li "string3\|string4"` (The `Z` flag to `grep` outputs zero terminators on its results list, which should be compatible with `xargs -0`)

Comment: @pilcrow That won't quite work in this circumstance, because the -print0 will just be printing the filenames, not selecting only filenames matched by the first grep. It's the output of the first grep that's going through the pipe, which is why I think the -Z flag on that is what's needed. Hard to tell without a box to play with, though :)

Comment: @Matt, yes, and there's more than one way to do it. :)

Comment: @pilcrow There always is! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it.  This should keep the total number of processes executed to a minimum:

```
find . -name \*.xml -print0          \   # List of *.xml files (NUL-terminated)
  | xargs -0 grep -Zli 'string[12]'  \   # is input to first grep, which sends (NUL-term'd)
  | xargs -0 grep -Li  'string[34]'      # file list to second grep
```

Thanks [Matt Gibson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300836/) for reminding us of the `-Z` flag to GNU grep.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice method. @Cicerone -- also note that @pilcrow and I are both assuming you need to escape your `*.xml` somehow to avoid shell expansion.

Comment: This one works too and it's extremely fast!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all in one `find` which avoids all the problems with spaces in filenames. Something like

```
find . -exec grep -liq "string1\|string2" {} \; -not -exec grep -liq "string3\|string4" {} \; -print
```

The "-q" suppresses all grep output. The `-exec` primary returns true when the process exits with 0 status, as grep does when it finds a match, and the `-not` primary reverses that. So we directly place two conditions on the `find`, and as a result we only print the filenames that satisfy both -- no pipe required!

Comment: I was just working out the details of this when your answer appeared.

Comment: Sorry @Colin. I hate when that happens to me :)

Comment: +1 for a solution where it is highly likely that the file is still in the disk cache when the second grep goes to work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, I think all you're missing is the -Z flag on the first `grep` to go along with the -0 that you were trying on your `xargs`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -liZ "string1\|string2" {} \; | xargs -0 grep -Li "string3\|string4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the limiting factor is CPU (i.e. your disk is fast) and you have more CPU cores, you can use GNU Parallel:

```
find . -type f| parallel grep -Lq foo {} '||' grep -l bar {}
```

By running the two `grep`s immediately after eachother chances are that the files are still in the disk cache. If the disk seeks are slow, you can add `-j1` to disable the parallelism.

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ